# AE resource /in-cse not found when trying to create AE

Tags: rest, http, onem2m

I'm trying to learn oneM2M standard using Eclipse OM2M. There is 1 infrastructure node (in-cse) and 1 middle node (ms-cse) which running the ipe sample.

I can GET information from the infrastructure node by sending the following

```bash
curl --request GET \
  --url 'http://localhost:8080/~/in-cse?=' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
  --header 'x-m2m-origin: admin:admin' \
  --data '<m2m: ae xmlns: m2m = "http://www.onem2m.org/xml/protocols" rn = "MY_SENSOR">

     <api> app-sensor </ api>

     <lbl> Type/sensor Category/temperature Location/home </lbl>

     <rr> false </ rr>

 </ m2m: ae>'
```

then I'm receiving

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<m2m:cb
    xmlns:m2m="http://www.onem2m.org/xml/protocols"
    xmlns:hd="http://www.onem2m.org/xml/protocols/homedomain" rn="in-name">
    <ty>5</ty>
    <ri>/in-cse</ri>
    <ct>20230306T095413</ct>
    <lt>20230306T095413</lt>
    <acpi>/in-cse/acp-264201706</acpi>
    <cst>1</cst>
    <csi>in-cse</csi>
    <srt>1 2 3 4 5 9 14 15 16 17 23 28</srt>
    <poa>http://127.0.0.1:8080/</poa>
</m2m:cb>
```

but when I'm doing

```bash
curl --request POST \
  --url 'http://localhost:8080/~/in-cse?=' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
  --header 'x-m2m-origin: admin:admin' \
  --data '<m2m: ae xmlns: m2m = "http://www.onem2m.org/xml/protocols" rn = "MY_SENSOR">

     <api> app-sensor </ api>

     <lbl> Type/sensor Category/temperature Location/home </lbl>

     <rr> false </ rr>

 </ m2m: ae>'
```

I got `AE resource /in-cse not found.`

what i'm doing wrong ?

(I'm using the default configuration provided by OM2M)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of problems with your requests.

First, in the second request the URL looks a bit strange. I think it should be `http://localhost:8080/~/in-cse` (without the "?=" at the end).

Second (but perhaps not the problem here), in the first request, an http GET request shouldn't have a body (the "--data" part). It is not really forbidden, but is ignored by the receiver and may have strange side effects.

Also, if you want to learn about oneM2M technology then I like to point to a series of oneM2M tutorials in the form of Jupyter Notebooks (disclosure: I am the author): https://wiki.onem2m.org/index.php?title=OneM2M_Tutorials_using_Jupyter_Notebooks You can either work through these tutorials online, or download them and install them locally. The tutorials also come with their own CSE.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have removed the --data field in the GET request and the "?=" in the POST, but the result is the same.

Comment: I just noticed that you are also missing the type in the "Content-Type" header. Could you try with " --header 'Content-Type: application/xml;ty=2' ? When sending a CREATE request you need to specify the resource type, otherwise the http POST will be taken as a notification request.

Comment: Funny, I just saw it a few minutes ago and corrected it.
Now the command is 
```
curl --request POST   --url 'http://localhost:8080/~/in-cse'   --header 'Content-Type: application/xml ; ty = 2'   --header 'x-m2m-origin: admin:admin'   --data '<m2m: ae xmlns: m2m = "http://www.onem2m.org/xml/protocols" rn = "MY_SENSOR">

     <api> app-sensor </ api>

     <lbl> Type/sensor Category/temperature Location/home </lbl>

     <rr> false </ rr>

 </ m2m: ae>'
```
But I still got a "AE resource /in-cse not found." error.

Comment: om2m always had some problems with resource addresses. Perhaps you could try ".../in-cse" (without the "~") (sorry, I don't have om2m installed here to try myself). Again, I would like to point to the Jupyter notebooks where these kind of requests are explained. Also, you might try to use my CSE implementation: https://github.com/ankraft/ACME-oneM2M-CSE which is compliant to the standard, except it does support JSON, not XML.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try your jupyther notebook but I work with the team that made OM2M so I have to solve this problem, I will explore further and update the solution when I got it.

Comment: Ah, ok. Then good luck. BTW, I remember that om2m used to use "-" instead of "~". But perhaps that has been fixed in the meantime?